# Align xticks on top of axes with bars in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have the following bar graph.

[image]

I want the xticks on the x-axis on top of the graph to align with the bars.

So rather than spacing `[105, 20, 75, ...]` evenly, I want them spaced so that 105 is above the first bar, 4 is above the last bar, etc.

How would this be done?

**Example code** (that generates above graph):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [10, 20, 30, 40, 90]
y = [7, 8, 12, 25, 50]
other = [105, 20, 75, 20, 4]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(x,y)

ax.set_title('title', y=1.04)
ax.set_xlabel('x label')
ax.set_ylabel('y label')

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90)
ax2.set_xticklabels(other)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is to manually specify the xtick locations using [`ax2.set_xticks(locations)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks). Also, you want to ensure that the xlims are the same for both `ax` and `ax2`. This guarantees that the ticks will line up with the bars. We can do this with [`set_xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim) and [`get_xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xlim). If we modify the `ax2` portion of the code and take these changes into consideration, we would get the following.

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()

# Ensure that the x limits are the same
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())

# Set the labels to be the values we want and rotated
ax2.set_xticklabels(other, rotation=90)

# Place the xticks on ax2 at the bar centers
ax2.set_xticks(x)
```

[image]